# slurm - how to start job once two previous jobs are completed?

Tags: bash, slurm

I am having some syntax issues when trying to get task3 to begin only after both tasks 1 and 2 are completed. At the moment I have a chain and this is a bit inefficient for my work.

tasks:

```
task1=$(sbatch --parsable --job-name="${JobID1}" ${Dir}/something.sh)
sleep 2
echo ${task1}
task1=${task1} 

task2=$(sbatch --parsable --dependency=aftercorr:$task1 --job-name="${JobID2}" ${Dir}/somethingelse.sh)
sleep 2
echo ${task2}
task2=${task2} 

task3=$(sbatch --parsable --dependency=aftercorr:$task2 --job-name="${JobID3}" ${Dir}/somethingelse.sh)
sleep 2
echo ${task3}
task3=${task3}
```

Whereas I would love it if task3 would begin after both tasks 1 + 2 are complete. Just don't understand the syntax of slurm enough to do so.

```
task3=$(sbatch --parsable --dependency=aftercorr:$task1,$task2 --job-name="${JobID3}" ${Dir}/somethingelse.sh)
sleep 2
echo ${task3}
task3=${task3}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man sbatch`:

```
aftercorr:job_id[:jobid...]
                     A task of this job array can begin execution after the corresponding task ID in the specified job has completed successfully (ran to completion with an exit code of zero).
```

So you only need to put all the JobIDs separated by colons:

```
task3=$(sbatch --parsable --dependency=aftercorr:$task1:$task2 --job-name="${JobID3}" ${Dir}/somethingelse.sh)
```